# How to display date as DD MMM YYYY imported from .csv

Tags: date, csv, sas

I have a service that picks up a .csv and processes it to .sas7bdat.

I modify an existing .sas template by filling in variable names, length, and specifying output location.

I have a scenario in which my .csv has a date formatted as 'DD MMM YYYY'. I need to preserve this format to the output file. The predefined formats allow for 'DDMMMYYY' and 'DD-MMM-YYYY'. I have tried these format types in the template.

Below is the template with standard character type:

```
LIBNAME TempSrc "C:\Temp";
proc import datafile="\\***\FileLocation\file.csv"
        out=mydata dbms=dlm replace;
        DELIMITER= ",";
        getnames=yes;
        options ExtendObsCounter=yes;
RUN;
DATA TempSrc.fileName;
    attrib      DATEVAR length=$11  format=$11.     informat=$11.       label='Date'
            ;
            set work.mydata;
RUN;
```

How can I modify this code to output a date as follows '01 JAN 2000'

**EDIT:**

How can I output this value to the .sas7bdat as a character value?

Comment: So your _input_ CSV has '01 JAN 2000' and you want the _output_ dataset to also contain '01 JAN 2000'?  Your existing code already does this, by reading the value in as a character variable.  So..  what is the actual problem?  Did you want to convert it to an actual date value (so, numeric) but format it to display 'DD MMM YYYY' ?

Comment: If I leave the length as character, I get the error "ERROR: Variable DATEVAR has been defined as both character and numeric.
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a default format to display as DD MMM YYYY so it's necessary to roll your own.  I believe the following gives you what you are trying to achieve:

```
proc format;
picture ddmmmyy
  other= '%0d %b %Y' (datatype=date);
run;

data have;
  datevar='01 JAN 2000';
run;

data want;
  set have;
  actualdatevar=input(datevar,anydtdte11.);
  format actualdatevar ddmmmyy11.;
run;
```

gives:

[image]

Note that you cannot convert a character variable to numeric, so you may wish to create a new variable and then drop the old one (can also rename the new variable so that you end up with the same named variable).

EDIT1: to apply to specific answer (now situation is clearer)

The following should achieve what is needed:

```
LIBNAME TempSrc "C:\Temp";

proc format;
picture ddmmmyy
  other= '%0d %b %Y' (datatype=date);
run;

proc import datafile="\\***\FileLocation\file.csv"
        out=mydata dbms=dlm replace;
        DELIMITER= ",";
        getnames=yes;
        options ExtendObsCounter=yes;
RUN;
/* if all you need to do is apply the format, you may be better using proc datasets */
DATA TempSrc.fileName;  
  set work.mydata;  
  format DATEVAR ddmmmyy11. ;
RUN;
```

EDIT2: converting to character so that it is displayed correctly in universal viewer (without the custom format)

```
LIBNAME TempSrc "C:\Temp";

proc format;
picture ddmmmyy
  other= '%0d %b %Y' (datatype=date);
run;

proc import datafile="\\***\FileLocation\file.csv"
        out=mydata dbms=dlm replace;
        DELIMITER= ",";
        getnames=yes;
        options ExtendObsCounter=yes;
RUN;
/* convert numeric to character via rename */
DATA TempSrc.fileName;  
  set work.mydata (rename=(DATEVAR=DATEVAR2));  
  DATEVAR=put(DATEVAR2,ddmmmyy11.);
  drop DATEVAR2;
RUN;
```

Comment: This does not work. The output file displays the unformatted day value.

I inserted the proc format after the proc import and before the data step. Then changed DATEVAR to format=ddmmmyy11.

Comment: Hi Dan - I had to create a reproducable example in order to demonstrate the format and explain the concepts.  As I understand it now, your input variable was NUMERIC and therefore all you needed was the proc format (note that it is only necessary to have this _before_ the data step, the position relative to the proc import does not matter).  Is your problem solved now?  Did my answer help?

Comment: This does not seem to work when the .sas7bdat is viewed outside the SAS tool that generated it. So, when I open it in a universal viewer, the ddmmmyy11 formatting is lost.

Comment: If that is your requirement then I suggest converting it to a character variable